# Carrousel con Php

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy intentando crear un carrousel con valor devuelto de función.
El problema surge en el html que integro.
Basicamente son las publicaciones  mas populares, cualquier sugerencia me ayudaria a avanzar.
Muchas gracias!!

```
          function most_liked_activities( $args = array(), $result = '' ) { 
            $defaults = array(
                "numberOf"    => 10,
                "period"      => 'all',
                "sizeOf"      => 32,
                "trim"        => 18,
                "profile_url" => '',
                "show_count"  => true,
                "show_thumb"  => true,
                "before_item" => '<li>',
                "after_item"  => '</li>'
            );
            // Parse args
            $settings       = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
            // Extract settings
            extract($settings);
            $activities = wp_ulike_get_most_liked_activities( $numberOf, $period );

            foreach ($activities as $activity) {
                $activity_permalink = function_exists('bp_activity_get_permalink') ? bp_activity_get_permalink( $activity->id ) : '';
                $activity_action    = ! empty( $activity->content ) ? $activity->content : $activity->action;
             $titulo = bp_activity_get_meta( $activity->id, 'titulo' );
            $post_count = get_counter_value( $activity->id, 'activity', 'like', $period );
            $url_image = bp_activity_get_meta( $activity->id, 'url_image' );
            $image = '<img class="w3-border w3-padding" src="https://xx.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/image.jpg" width="80" height="80" >';        
           $result .=   print'<div class="full"><div class="medios1">'.$image.
                        '</div> <div class="medios" ><strong><a class="name" href='.$activity_permalink.'>'. $titulo.'</a></strong></br></div>  </div>';
            }
            
        ?>
```

A partir de aqui esta el error, no puedo lograr visualizar nada:

````
    ``` <div class="yz-mobile-nav">
        <div class="yz-mobile-nav-item yz-show-activity-menu">
                
        <div class="carousel-inner" roles="listbox">
        <?php for($i=0; $i < count(10); $i++) { ?>
          <div class="item <?php if ($i==0) { echo 'active'; }?>">
        <?php echo $result;?>
             </div>
             <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
             
        <?php   
    }?>
````

ACTUALIZACION
Modifique con estos resultados y logre crear un carrousel con cada imagen.
Sin embargo aparece una imagen por vez (yo queria dos) y al finalizar el carrousel se cierra, no se vuelve a repetir.

```
               $result .=  print    '<div class="item"><div style="width: 50%;">'.$image. '</div>   <div class="medios" style="width: 50%;"><strong><a class="name" href='.$activity_permalink.'>'. $titulo.'</a></strong></br><h5 class="pre">ARS'.$precio_actual.'</h5></div> </div>';
                }
            }
             ?>

      <div class="container"> 
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
    
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
          </div>
    
      <?php echo most_liked_activities();?>
    
        <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Necesito explicarme primero en una respuesta, así que perdonen las reglas.*

---

```
<?php for($i=0; $i < count(10); $i++) { ?>
      <div class="item <?php if ($i==0) { echo 'active'; }?>">
<?php echo $result;?>
```

En esta parte del código, por alguna razón que no comprendo, estás haciendo un `count(10)`.
`count` solo puede contar objetos o arrays, no `int`.
Por lo que para empezar a imprimir algo en esa parte, debes dejarlo de este modo:

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) { ?>
    <div class="item <?php if ($i == 0) {echo 'active'; } ?>"><?php echo $result ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

De este modo, tendrás una impresión correcta de `$result`.
No solo de la variable, sino del `HTML` mismo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo otr que tengo duda, es por que estás haciendo un `print`  en `$result`, lamentablemente no puedo conseguir ese resultado, pero quitarle el print hará que se muestren el resto de imagenes supongo.

Comment: gracias Excorpion, intente incorporar el código brindado pero genera el carrousel con todos los elementos en mismo slider. Me tomo el atrevimiento de mostrarte el avance con una actualización que agregue.

Comment: Si elimino print de $result, no se ve nada en carrousel.

Comment: Buenas @jackie !! volviendo hoy a revisarte. Parece que tu problema ha cambiado ahora ??

Comment: resuelto, gracias!